# How do I look at my app's logcat on cell phone

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

As the title, how can I look at the logcat of my app on my phone?  I think since Android 4.1, root access is required to view logcat.  How what can I do to

Comment: enable debug mode, plug it in, see the logcat. no root access required, obviously.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, but I am really new at this.  After I enable the debug mode and plug the phone in, what do I do?  Do I run the emulator or app on my phone?

Comment: Never mind.  I think I found what I need here.  http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 1):

if your phone has an `adb` binary, try this way:

1. enable ADB over Wi-Fi, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) out.
2. in your app, execute `adb connect 127.0.0.1` then `adb logcat`, parse the output.

This might work on some phones, not tested. Good luck.